# VSCode Extension Activation Event for when document is changed

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am writing a VSCode extension in JavaScript that verifies some properties of the file. It needs to be run every time the user types something / the document changes. I was wondering if there is an activation event (https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/activation-events)
that can happen whenever the document changes? If not, how do I trigger the extension I am writing to run whenever the current file is changed?

Comment: you have to subscribe to the DocumentChanged Event, activate with `*` to be activated for all languages

Comment: @rioV8 Do you know where I can find an example for how to register that command? I tried the following line in my extension.js file:
`let disposable2 = vscode.commands.registerCommand('*', function () {`
but it doesn't register.

Comment: `*` is the activation event in `package.json`

Comment: @rioV8 I have the following in my `package.json`
`"activationEvents": [ "*"],`
I don't know how to register the command though. What code do I need to put in my `extension.js`?
Do you have an example js project I can look at?

Comment: search the VSC API Reference for the exact event name and then search the example extensions

Comment: @rioV8 I think this may be the wrong activation event. According to the VSC API Reference, `*` is the startup event not the document change event https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/activation-events#Start-up

Comment: you want your extension to be active for any language so you need to get the `activate()` function be called at the start of VSC, in `activate` you subscribe to the `DocumentChanged` Event

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does.

```js
    vscode.workspace.onDidChangeTextDocument((e: vscode.TextDocumentChangeEvent) => {
        console.log('Document changed.');
        console.log(e.document.isDirty);
    });
```